# hiding title/artwork from soundloud embedable widget

Tags: soundcloud

I am looking for a way to hide artwork/title/other identifying information from embedable soundcloud widget. This is for a quiz project, so the user should be able to play the recording, without seeing the author/title. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the widget offscreen and control the playback with the Widget API.